# conect to a database in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

I can not to connect to a database in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012. It is unable to give the error message "I am Connected" when I change the name and so on.

I did the database in Access.

What I want is to connect to my database.

```
Public conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0;data source=database1.accdb; persist Security info = false")


Public Sub con()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("I am connected")

    Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: where are you calling `con`?

Comment: Your data source assumes the database is in the same directory as the executable.  It probably isn't.

Comment: If the connection fails then an exception will be thrown.  You're catching that exception and displaying the information about it, yet you decided that it would be a good idea to keep that information secret from the people whom you want to help you.  That is a bad plan.

Comment: Argh! You open a connection but never close or dispose it! Check out `Using...End Using`

Comment: caracas venezuerla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's at least close and dispose for when you have success.

```
Private conString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0;data source=database1.accdb; persist Security info = false"
Private Sub TestConnection()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(conString)
        cn.Open()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: mary thanks vary much for your answer and helping and i am from caracas venezuela

Comment: @CesarGomez Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am from Houston, Texas, USA